# how to show $\|f\|_p\leq (m(E))^{1/p-1/q}\|f\|_q$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $m(E)<\infty$ and $f\in L_q(E)$, show that $\|f\|_p\leq (m(E))^{1/p-1/q} \|f\|_q$, for $1\leq p< q<\infty$ (and consequently $L_q(E)\subset L_p(E)$, whenever $m(E)<\infty$)

How to start such a problem?

It seems clear that some sort of version of Holder's inequality will have to be employed...

Comment: $E$ is a measurable subset of the real numbers here.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: notice that by Jensen's inequality,

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{m(E)}\int |f|^p\;dm \bigg)^{q/p} \leq \frac{1}{m(E)}\int |f|^q dm$$ which reduces to the desired claim. The probability measure we are using is $\mu(A):=m(A)/m(E)$ with our convex function $\phi(x) = x^{q/p}$ and integrand $|f|^p$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $r = q/p$ and $r'$ be the conjugate exponent of $r$. Note that $|f|^p \in L_r(E)$ and $\chi_E \in L_{r'}(E)$.